# Asymptotic Notation Analysis Problem

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm new here. I have some question on asymptotic analysis
I am trying to calculate the Big-O of these five functions and rank them up:

a: $$2^{\log(n)}$$
b: $$2^{2\log(n)}$$
c: $$n^{5\over2}$$
d: $$2^{n^2}$$
e: $$n^2\log(n)$$

These are my approaches:

a: $$O(n)$$ because I log the both sides and cancel out the log

b: $$O(n)$$ same as the approach of a
c: $$O(n^{5\over2})$$
d: $$O(2^{2n})$$
e: $$n^2\log n$$

So d is definitely the largest.
The second largest would be c because $$n^{5\over2}$$ is just $$n^2\times n^{1\over2}$$ and  $$n^{1\over2}$$ is larger than $$\log n$$ so the third would be e.
Then a and b are the same.
So to rank from the lowest growing rate, I get "abecd". But my answers are wrong, can someone explain, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong if it is $\log_2$. In general $2^{\log_b(n)} = n^{\log_b(2)} = n^{\log_2(b)^{-1}}$ and so the asymptotic behaviour would depend on $b$.

Wait your reasoning for (d) is wrong. $2^{n^2} = 2^{(n^2)} \ne (2^n)^2$... Though it really is the biggest, much bigger than what you thought.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for spotting my incorrect reasoning in (d)!

Comment: But what you're saying is that the ascending order "abecd" should be correct?

Comment: @RexYuan: Yes it should be correct if it is the binary log.